# How do I handle null equality in a generic context?

Tags: c#, generics, equality

I'm writing a generic method and I want to test a generic var for `null`. The operator `==` cannot be used since the compiler doesn't know if whether it's a value or reference type. So I used `Equals`

```
public void MyGenericMethod<T>(T myGenericVar)
{
    bool isNull = myGenericVar.Equals(default(T));
    [...]
}
```

It happens that if `T` is a reference type, `default(T)` is actually `null` and calling `Equals` on null produces a `NullReferenceException`.

How do I handle null equality in a generic way?

Comment: Calling `variable.Equals(null)` does not throw an NRE, but calling `null.Equals(null)` does. Your `myGenericVar` seems to be null. Does `object.Equals(myGenericVar, null)` (or `default(T)`) solve your problem?

Comment: You may use something like `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(myGenericVar, default);`, but `T` should properly implement `Equals` method

Comment: why not use ```myGenericVar is null```

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski please make an answer